# How to draw hexagonal shape using python dxfwrite

Tags: python, parsing, shapefile, shapely, dxf

How to draw a hexagonal( or any polygon with more than 4 sides)  shape in python using dxfwrite? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the POLYLINE entity:

http://pythonhosted.org/dxfwrite/entities/polyline.html

```
from dxfwrite import DXFEngine as dxf

dwg = dxf.drawing('polyline.dxf')

points = [(0, 3), (2, 0), (5, 0), (7, 3), (5, 6), (2, 6)]
polyline = dxf.polyline(points)
polyline.close()
dwg.add(polyline)

dwg.save()
```